# Scheme - Function recursion error

Tags: list, recursion, filter, scheme

This function reads in a list and swaps values, but only when there's a key in the hash table that matches an element in the list. However, the list that is read in could contain other lists, and I want to check this recursively. I use `if (list? elementInList)` to determine whether I'm dealing with a list, so I can search that list for elements that may need to be swapped using a recursive call. I tried to do this but it's not handling the lists within the list correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
(define (let-helper L)
    (map (lambda (x) (swap x (hash-ref *variable-table* x) L))
         (filter (lambda (x) 
                     (if (list? x)
                         (let-helper x) ;; recursion here
                         (hash-has-key? *variable-table* x)))
                 L)))
```

Comment: A few examples would be useful.

Comment: I put 2 examples in the comments of the 1st answer. i like ur username

Comment: It just takes a list that contains a functions, which could be anything to evaulate such as: (+ i 3) or (- (+ 5 i) (* j 7))

Comment: okay, so basically it doesnt need the swap function just (hash-ref *variable-table* x) and it works. thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest just `flatten`ing the list so that you can continue to use `map` and `filter` like this:

```
(define (let-helper L)
  (map (lambda (x) (swap x (hash-ref *variable-table* x) L))
       (filter (lambda (x) (hash-has-key? *variable-table* x))
               (flatten L))))
```

Otherwise to get it to work would require writing it without `map` and `filter` like this:

```
(define (let-helper L)
  (let ((action (lambda (x) (swap x (hash-ref *variable-table* x) L)))
        (predicate (lambda (x) (hash-has-key? *variable-table* x))))

    (let loop ((a '()) (L L))
      (if (null? L)
          (reverse a)
          (if (list? (car L))
              (loop (cons (let-helper (car L)) a) (cdr L))
              (if (predicate (car L))
                  (loop (cons (action (car L)) a) (cdr L))
                  (loop a (cdr L))))))
```

Untested.

---

So the swap should only occur if the hash has the key but the returned list should still have the elements that weren't swapped? If so then not removing the element from the list of it isn't a key would fix that like this:

```
(define (let-helper L)
  (map (lambda (x) 
         (if (list? x) 
             (let-helper x) 
             (if (hash-has-key? *variable-table* x) 
                 (swap x (hash-ref *variable-table* x) L) 
                 x))))
       L)
```

Or

```
(define (let-helper L)
  (let ((action (lambda (x) (swap x (hash-ref *variable-table* x) L)))
        (predicate (lambda (x) (hash-has-key? *variable-table* x))))

    (let loop ((a '()) (L L))
      (if (null? L)
          (reverse a)
          (if (list? (car L))
              (loop (cons (let-helper (car L)) a) (cdr L))
              (if (predicate (car L))
                  (loop (cons (action (car L)) a) (cdr L))
                  (loop (cons (car L) a) (cdr L))))))
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the sublists are functions, and need to stay in order.

Comment: What you have at the top I had initially, but say my input is (+ i 3) then it will produce a list like (+ (+ 1 3) 3). Another example: (+ (* 8 i) (/ 9 j)) will produce a list (+ (* 8 (* 8 1)) (/ 9 (/ 9 7))). so as you can see the variables are swapped but it also swaps in the whole list/sublist of where it was swapped as well. This is my problem, i want to swap out the variables only.